# CSS - Link not clickable inside absolute DIV - mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm not able to click links inside a div the is `position:absolute`. It seems to not work on mobile android as it works fine on the desktop in Chrome and even ie8.

As soon as I remove the style it works. The class msg-inner is only for jQuery which has it scrollTop no styling on it. I've read many answers and to use `z-index` or `position:relative` on the inner div but none works. I even tried using `position:fixed` on msg_container and same problem. The inner div scrolls and everything looks right but just the links are broken, BTW sporadically some will work and some don't. I took away all styling and just put plain links inside to see if it was a format issue and still nothing.

```
<div id="msg_container" class="absolute" style="overflow-y:auto;width:100%;height:75%">
    <div class="msg_inner">

.... stuff in here with links
</div><!--msg inner-->
    </div><!--msg_container-->
```

CSS

```
.absolute {
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `#msg_container` shouldn't have a position of absolute, the `.msg_inner` should.  Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="msg_container">
    <div class="msg_inner">
        .... stuff in here with links
    </div><!--msg inner-->
</div><!--msg_container-->
```

**CSS**

```
.msg_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.msg_inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Also note that I made `msg_container` a class, not an ID.  It's considered bad practice to have multiple ID's of the same name.  While I don't know your code of course, I assumed that you might have multiple `msg_container`s on a page... so I used a class instead.

Comment: Sorry That does not work. It messes up the formatting. I need msg_inner to scroll vertically inside of the msg_container, which is why I had overflow-y on it. It wont work with position relative or at least I can't it get it to work. I only have 1 div with the ID msg_container that's why I made it an ID.

Comment: Then why don't you just add `overflow-y: scroll` and a width and height to `.msg_inner`.  Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Well it does scroll. But everything get's messed up. I end up getting two scroll bars, one for msg_container and one for msg_inner. and both will move. I need msg_container to not have scroll bars and not move at all. Also it breaks my .scrollTop with jquery that scrolls to the bottom of msg_container on page load. Not sure whatelse to try.. uggghh

Comment: Give msg_container an overflow of hidden.  Honestly, it's considered bad design to have multiple scroll bars, but that's your call.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand. I DON'T want multiple scrollbars. The way I have it now, gives me only a scroll on the msg_container. However when I do how you have it, I don't want to put an exact height in px. I wanted to use percent. Your example seems to not work on the msg_container if I use height:75%; Why can't I use percentage?

Comment: It got cut off. What I was saying is I don't want multiple bars. However using your example, it won't let me use a percentage height. Only seems to work if I set a height in px, e.g. 400px. I want to use height:75%;. However it will still break my scrollTop jQuery function in the end as well

Comment: Could you maybe make a jsFiddle about it (http://jsfiddle.net/)?  I'm happy to work out a solution, but I need it in context which I can see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28180/discussion-between-cereallarceny-and-pjack)

Comment: I don't see you in chat. This is how it works now for me, but links do not work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/teaQk/3/

Comment: You've got some Javascript errors because the link you're trying to load is Google.  Some websites may block their website from being loaded into an iframe via Javascript.  This is the way jsFiddle displays websites.  Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teaQk/4/ The last link (link 20) is my website, which opens fine because I don't employ the block that Google does.  Try the code on your site, it should work if you don't use Google.

Comment: Google was just an example. The REALLY links are to places on mysite, like images, profiles etc. They work fine otherwise. That is my whole point. The code works fine on desktop. My problem is mobile as I mentioned. It doesn't work on the android mobile but works ok on desktop Chrome etc.

Comment: Right, keep in mind that scrollTo is bound to be different because of the way phones render height.  Screens will render things different, not to mention touch events are handled different than click events.  I'm afraid I can't help you any further seeing as I can't duplicate your issue for myself.